# How to use two pins/ports in modelica and Powersytems library

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am new to modelica and I am having difficulty dealing with two pins/ports. For example I am using the class `PowerSystems.AC3ph.Inverters.Inverter`, and I am not sure how to connect the `inverter.DC` and `inverter.vPhasor` pins/ports.

Currently I am connecting pin/port like so:

`connect(pVArray.p, inverter.DC) annotation(...);`
`connect(constant1.y, inverter.vPhasor) annotation(...);`

The current problem is that `PVSystems.Electrical.PVArray` has two outputs: the positive electric pin, and the negative electric pin, while the inverter only has a single Two_Pin_P DC. I am not sure how to connect both.

`inverter.vPhasor` needs two inputs :

`Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput[2] vPhasor_in if use_vPhasor_in "{abs(v), phase(v)}"`

How could I send two real inputs to a single pin? Right now I can only send one as seen above.

I am currently getting an error because of the `inverter.vPhasor` because of that

> [1] 13:31:47 Translation Error
> [cert_mg: 65:3-66:62]: The type of variables constant1.y and inverter.vPhasor
> are inconsistent in connect equations.

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue is, that the `PowerSystems` library defines custom interfaces. As an example, the connector `DC` in `PowerSystems.AC3ph.Inverters.Inverter` actually contains the same variables like `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin` but as a vector. A single connection from `PowerSystems.AC1ph_DC.Ports.TwoPin_p` therefore creates two ideal electrical connections.

This is in contrast to the interfaces used by `PVSystems`, which reuses the interfaces from the `Modelica` (Standard) library. If I understood you question correctly, this is the reason why the connection

```
connect(pVArray.p, inverter.DC) annotation(...)
```

is actually not a valid connection, because the connectors differ. Basically this means that `PowerSystems` would connect both pins used in `PVSystems.Electrical.PVArray` with a single connection, which is why you don't find a possibility to connect the negative pin of the `PVArray`.

For the inputs of `PowerSystems.AC3ph.Inverters.Inverter`, did you look at `PowerSystems.Examples.AC3ph.Inverters.InverterToLoad`? It demonstrates how to connect them...

Comment: Do you know of any photovoltaic arrays or solar panel/systems that are compatible with powersystems. I found many PV libraries in modelica but none seem to inverter but none seem to have all the power components I need for my microgrid. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not find a solar panel in pvsystems.

Comment: I don't know any PV-model with interfaces compatible to the `PowerSystems` library. As an alternative, It should be possible to use `PowerSystems.AC3ph.Sources.PQsource` with `use_pq_in = true` and computing the power input as a signal from some other PV-library. This could make sense if you need to use `PowerSystems` for a certain reason...

Comment: Is there any other library that you know of in openmodelica that has 3 phase modeling tools, solar PV, and battery storage? Thanks

Comment: There is a number of libraries for photovoltaics, `PVSystems` or `PhotoVolatics`. For three-phase modeling you could use `Modelica.Electrical.Polyphase` or `Modelica.Electrical.QuasiStatic`. An inverter is included in `Modelica.Electrical.PowerConverters` but it is switched and therefore comparably slow. The question is what the use-case actual is...